# How can I make a Object-Oriented Program of Login?

Tags: c#, oop

What is the problem of this codes below? My codes give me some error. I want to used a object-oriented program on our project but its not working fine. Can somebody help me regarding to my problem

```
 class Login
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Userpassword { get; set; }

        public Login()
        {
            this.Username = user; //does not exist in the current context
            this.Userpassword = pass; //does not exist in the current context
        }

        private void ClearTexts(string user, string pass)
        {
            user = String.Empty;
            pass = String.Empty;
        }

        public void Login(string user, string pass)
        {
            int count = 0;
            Connection connection = new Connection();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Login";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;

            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully!");
                frmLogin.Hide(); //required for the non-static field,method
                frmMain.showMe(this); //best overloaded method match...
            }
            else
            {
                txtPassword.Focus(); /does not exist in the current context
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Is Incorrect");
                txtUserName.Text = ""; //does not exist in the current context
                txtPassword.Text = ""; //does not exist in the current context

            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! *"My codes give me some error"*. That's not very helpful. Please include relevant details, like what error and what line, so we have some idea where to look. You can edit the question using the 'edit' link above the comments to add this information.

Comment: Sorry for that. I comment the errors.

Comment: Your constructor where you assign Username and Password does not have any parameters which is why you're probably getting "does not exist in the current context" errors.

Comment: `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` will never exist as you dont define them

Comment: Two different classes have two different scopes. `txtUsername` is probably on the form, while this is a separate class, so `txtUsername` is not _in scope_ `frmLogin.txtUsername.Text` might work. It's not the best from a code structure perspective to have this much form logic in this separate class, but that's probably something to solve later when you have a bit more experience.

Comment: How can I define it? And where do I define it ? in class or in the partial class class ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Login()` constructor without parameters. Instead move the fields settings Down to the constructor with parameters like this:

```
   public void Login(string user, string pass)
    {

        this.Username = user;
        this.Userpassword = pass;
        // more code here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Login(){
 this.Username = user; //does not exist in the current context
 this.Userpassword = pass; //does not exist in the current context
}
```

`user` and `pass` are not parameters to your function so they don't exist. You already have a constructor that takes in a user and pass so this one should either set them to null or just not exist and force the use of the user/pass constructor